# Middle point of an arc

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, trigonometry

I have coordinates of two points, i.e., $X\equiv(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $Y\equiv(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, connected with an arc located on a desired surface. Given only this information, how can I compute the middle point of this arc?

Thanks!

PS: It would be nice to have an answer which can later be implemented efficiently on MATLAB/Mathematica since I need this to generate a surface through blockMesh. Also, a solution for 2D would work, too, i.e., for $x_3=0=y_3$.

Comment: By *"middle point of an arc located on a desired surface"*, do you mean the midpoint of the [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) on the surface between points X and Y?  If you do, then it all depends on how you define the surface.  If planar, it is trivial, and matches the midpoint of the line segment if the endpoints are both on the plane.  If spherical, it is again trivial if the center of the spherical surface is at origin.  If a single biquadratic or bicubic patch, there might be an analytical answer.  In all cases, the surface definition is key.

Comment: If your arc is arc-length parametrized, say $\gamma : [a,b] \to S$ where $S$ is your surface, I guess the midpoint of the arc refers to $\gamma(\frac{a+b}{2})$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks. Right, but I don't have an explicit expression for $\gamma(\cdot)$ in my case.

Comment: @Glärbo Thanks, yes, of the geodesic. However, in my case, these two points are on a semi-ellipsoid that I am trying to generate.

Comment: @kk17: What do you know about the surface, then?  If you are trying to generate it, you surely have *something* controlling it, because if you didn't, you'd just go "well, we have nothing to work with, so I'll go with the physicists' first approximation: all cows are spherical."  Please describe what you have to work with; don't leave out constraints or details you know but "think" are not relevant.  Only then can we help you.  Numerical values are not important, but having the list of datums/features you expect to have at hand at runtime, is the crucial missing key here.

Comment: For example, if the surface was indeed spherical, knowing the radius $r$ and the two points $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ on the surface would NOT be enough to determine where the middle point of the geodesic between those two are; we could find the *circle* it is on, but that's it.  On the other hand, if we had $\vec{o}$ describing the center of the sphere, we'd have a solution.  The case were $\lVert\vec{x}-\vec{o}\rVert \ne \lVert \vec{y}-\vec{o}\rVert$ would need checking and more work (because it'd no longer be on the surface of the sphere, and involved "elevation").  [...]

Comment: *We need to know what we know of the surface when we need to produce the middle point of the geodesic*.  We don't need those as numerical values, but we need to know if say the surface is defined as a surface of rotation, or say as some sort of elliptical approximation of the isosurface of a complex [metaball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaball).  Otherwise, the best *anyone* can do is, *"It's the midpoint of the geodesic on that surface, duh"*, because without information, there is no possibility of meaningful answers either.  Math isn't magic.

Comment: It seems that the arc is not well defined - why not having many arcs on the surface?